# GAE: Is it possible to build web service with endpoint within firewall?

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, firewall

I'm planning to build a two-tier application, with a back-end (java, possibly spring MVC) which delivers JSON up to a front-end (PHP, Drupal7). I only want the front-end application exposed to the outside world and in a traditional environment I would probably stick the back-end on some ports inside the firewall (assuming both parts run within the FW).

Is this possible to do in the Google App Engine environment?

Comment: How about -- (A) API authentication for your backend app, and; (B)  not publishing the Java app's GAE URL or API doc; be sufficient ? It'd be artly security through obscurity (no published information / URL) and partly proactive authentication (of API). Making it almost impossible for anyone to access your Java app directly. I'm an absolute newbie with GAE and web app development - who has just read bunch of articles and SO Q&As -- so take the suggestion with a big pinch of salt.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to run GAE inside your firewall. It runs on Google's servers.

Comment: Actually, I wasn't referring to my firewall, more to ensuring that the back-end application could only be accessed from the front-end application (2 separate applications on GAE, using different stacks) and not directly from the outside world.

Answer (score 0):

You can do basic things like blocking IPs but its not really necessary. Since your 'front end' has the php backend you can call from there your appengine with a secret parameter (as in "myapp.appspot.com?key=sE34sdJSjUy" ) Its very simple security and since no one can see that url (in your php backend), its as good as any other authentication method.